# Why is terraform plan always returning exit code 0 even when there are new resources to add?

Tags: bash, terraform

Terraform offers the following exit codes:

```
0 = Succeeded with empty diff (no changes)
1 = Error
2 = Succeeded with non-empty diff (changes present)
```

I need to perform `terraform apply` only if any new resources need to be added or there are any changes to apply.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No changes, not applying"
elif [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Terraform plan failed"
    exit 1
elif [ $? -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Terraform apply needed"
fi
```

But I am getting exit code `0`, even for a `terraform plan` command which outputs:

```
Plan: 9 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

What is the issue?

Comment: You don't show your actual `terraform plan` command here, are you using the option `-detailed-exitcode`?

Answer (score 10):

For `terraform plan` to return those exit codes, you must supply the `-detailed-exitcode` option as detailed in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html#detailed-exitcode).

> -detailed-exitcode - Returns a detailed exit code when the command exits.

---

This should be what your `terraform plan` command should look like, otherwise you will get an exit code of `0` regardless of output:

```
terraform plan -detailed-exitcode ...
```